# Getting rid of REMIND and LATER resolutions in Bugzilla

Tags: workflow, customization, bugzilla

Today, our team once again stumbled upon old bugs being resolved with LATER or REMIND, and it's high likely that we'll forget about them soon again. Both of these *non-resolutions* tend to get out of sight when mixed into resolved bugs. The Mozilla team itself agreed on removing them <sup>[1]</sup> for their installation and many other projects have followed since. Using LATER and REMIND is merely a source of confusion.

So also we decided to disable<sup>[2]</sup> them:

1. *Administration* > *Field values* > *Resolution*
2. for both values: unchecked property *enabled for bugs*

But **they don't disappear** from the user interface for bugs. Is it broken, have I to *delete* the values instead? What am I doing wrong?

---

- <sup>[1]</sup> The discussion has held in [35839 – REMIND and LATER considered harmful to bugzilla.mozilla.org](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35839)
- <sup>[2]</sup> deleting them seemed not to be appropriate due to the already existing bugs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now (after having changed the language from German to English for asking here) I tried it again, and the values aren't available any more. I suffered probably only from a caching effect.